# Light rays from point light three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way to see the light rays from a point light in a Three js scene. I have tried fog but it makes the whole objects in the scene the color of fog.

```
 var width = $('#g_pre_emo').width();

 var scene = new THREE.Scene();
 scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xffff00, 0, 10);
 var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, width / 500, 0.1, 1000);
 var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: false});
 renderer.setSize(width, 500);

 $('#g_pre_emo').append(renderer.domElement);


 var intensity = 2.5;
 var distance = 5;
 var decay = 2.0;

 var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040); // soft white light
 scene.add(light);

renderer.shadowMap.Enabled = true;
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
var happyGroup = new THREE.Object3D();
var sadGroup = new THREE.Object3D();
var angryGroup = new THREE.Object3D();
var relaxedGroup = new THREE.Object3D();

scene.add(happyGroup);
scene.add(sadGroup);
scene.add(angryGroup);
scene.add(relaxedGroup);
var c1 = 0xffff00;


var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.25, 16, 8);
light1 = new THREE.PointLight(c1, intensity, distance, decay);
light1.add(new THREE.Mesh(sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: c1})));
scene.add(light1);

happyGroup.position.set(-3, 3, 0);
sadGroup.position.set(3, 3, 0);
angryGroup.position.set(-3, -3, 0);
relaxedGroup.position.set(3, -3, 0);


var happyGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 50, 50);
var happyMaterial = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var happySphere = new THREE.Mesh(happyGeometry, happyMaterial);
scene.add(happySphere);
happyGroup.add(happySphere);

var sadGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 50, 50);
var sadMaterial = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var sadSphere = new THREE.Mesh(sadGeometry, sadMaterial);
scene.add(sadSphere);
sadGroup.add(sadSphere);

var angryGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 50, 50);
var angryMaterial = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var angrySphere = new THREE.Mesh(angryGeometry, angryMaterial);
scene.add(angrySphere);
angryGroup.add(angrySphere);

var relaxedGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 50, 50);
var relaxedMaterial = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var relaxedSphere = new THREE.Mesh(relaxedGeometry, relaxedMaterial);
scene.add(relaxedSphere);
relaxedGroup.add(relaxedSphere);


renderer.gammaInput = true;
renderer.gammaOutput = true;
camera.position.z = 15;

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
 ;
render();
animate();
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}
```

If i run the above code the i cant see any fog in the scene 
the fiddle for above code is 
https://jsfiddle.net/bqv5ynbo/1/

Comment: Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question.  You can start by adding a [mcve] of the issue at hand

Answer (score 2):

Possibly, you can use [`VolumetricSpotlightMaterial`](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.volumetricspotlight) from Jerome Etienne.

For me it worked well for Three.js r71, though I haven't tried it with later revisions.

[Example](http://jeromeetienne.github.io/threex.volumetricspotlight/examples/basic.html) of usage

Answer (score 0):

'Light Rays' aren't an automatically occurring thing.
Typically, light rays are created using advanced pixel shaders (stencil/shadow projection over lit region / volumetric fog) or in simple cases by creating simple alpha-blended polygons with 'ray' textures applied.

A point light is simply a light that does not apply directional calculations during it's shading phase.  Instead, only distance based calculations are made.

Good Luck!

Comment: If i add spotlight will it produce rays in a scene with fog?

Comment: Can you send me a link?

Comment: Hi again Suhail, 
Those lines appear to me to be a helper mechanism to allow you to see which direction the directional light is pointing.  I don't think it serves any other purpose than to be a time saver (I usually did the same thing when creating light sources in DirectX projects).
A point source is a less confusing form of light as it doesn't point exclusively in one direction so there's reduced need for guidelines.

Comment: I just came across this which might help: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996600/threejs-understanding-where-lights-are