# ThreeJS understanding where lights are

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been trying for around 30 minutes to position a pointlight at the bottom of my model with very poor results. I don't know how many units my model is and I can't seem to exactly locate my light in the scene most of the time.

I tried adding a cube at the exact position of my pointlight but somehow adding another geometry to my scene breaks the texture update function for my main obj, so I guess that's out of the question.

Any tips on how to position lights with precision?

My code is at view-source:http://creativiii.com/3Dproject/

Answer (score 0):

Each geometry has a `boundingSphere` attribute that you can use to figure out the size of your object. https://threejs.org/docs/api/core/Geometry.html 
If the attribute does not have a value you can compute it using `geometry.computeBoundingSphere();`

As for the lights for each of the light types there is a helper function associated with it that will show you where the light is:

```
https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Helper#Reference/Extras.Helpers/HemisphereLightHelper
https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Helper#Reference/Extras.Helpers/DirectionalLightHelper
https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Helper#Reference/Extras.Helpers/PointLightHelper
https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Helper#Reference/Extras.Helpers/SpotLightHelper
```